# React JSX to string

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tostring

How can I convert the children of a React component to a string without it rendering?

```js
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  )
}

const Output = () => {
  return (
    <pre>
     {renderToString(
        <div>
          <MyComponent />
          <MyComponent />
          <MyComponent />
        </div>
      }
    </pre>
  )
}
```

How can I make the above show:

```
<div>
  <MyComponent />
  <MyComponent />
  <MyComponent />
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Ultimately I'm looking to show how the code for the component is written in a ui system. Trying to parse the children instead of writing the component twice. Any examples of open source websites demonstration ui components with a code block works too, and I'll just look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [react-code-blocks](https://react-code-blocks-rajinwonderland.vercel.app/?path=/story/code--default). Basically you can add any code, just like Stackoverflow.